# How i can detect when input values are change using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand why it doesn't work, It should print debug by console.log and i tried to use on change method also didn't work.

So, i can't find the way to fix, How i can solve this problem. Thank you for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=item-]").on('input', function() {
    console.log(this.val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-1" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-2" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-3" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-4" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
```

or

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#item-1").on('input', function() {
    console.log(this.val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-1" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-2" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-3" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-4" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
```

Comment: There should be a `TypeError` in the console because `this` is the `<input>` element and that has no `.val()` method. Either wrap `this` in a jQuery object or use `.value` instead

Comment: Ah crap. Subconsciously did this while redoing it as a snippet. I'll revise.

Comment: `$(this)` is jQuery Object & `this` is JS object which don't have function `.val()`. Use `this.value` or `$(this).val()`

Comment: I went wrong, Thank you so much everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in your event handler is the `<input>` element that triggered the event.
`.val()` is a jQuery method.

Either wrap `this` in a jQuery object

```
$(this).val()
```

Or use `.value`

```
this.value
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#item-1").on('input', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-1" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-2" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-3" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-4" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object:

```
console.log($(this).val());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=item-]").on('input', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-1" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-2" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-3" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-4" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
```

or use `this` natively and grab the [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue):

```
console.log(this.value);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=item-]").on('input', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-1" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-2" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-3" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-4" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">
```